# Работа с древовидной структурой и хранение ее в бд

Tags: c#, алгоритм, entity-framework

Есть WPF MVVM проект с деревом категорий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С деревом можно производить различные манипуляции: добавлять, удалять категории, перемещать внутри и между уровнями. Нужно хранить это дерево в базе данных (используется Entity Framework), обновлять записи при изменении дерева.

UPD: также есть записи продуктов, относящихся к категориям. Каждый продукт может относиться к одной или более категорий (отношение многие ко многим).

Подскажите, какой алгоритм лучше использовать и есть ли готовые модули на .Net?

Comment: Проще всего в с# - сериализация. Есть обычная (xml) есть бинарная. поиск на [so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) много примеров

Comment: @nick_n_a думал об этом. Но также будут храниться данные, относящиеся к категориям, и нужно сохранить связи для возможности выборки.

Comment: id у вас есть? Создаёте свойства, в него запишите выбор из id-обьекта. Сам обьект не ставьте признак "не сериализовать" (это нужно только если обьект может "2 раза" использоваться). Тот привер который привели вы - на нём не видно что вы хотите связать обьекты через id. Я думаю вам это не надо делать.

Comment: Вариант 2 - DataTable, он позволяет сохранить/загрузить таблицу, если у вас есть "выборка" никто не мешает вам  `DataSource <-> DataTable <-> IDataReader` манипулировать данными, подставляя вместо базы файл.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Если использовать сериализацию, не получится построить связи между категориями и продуктами. Хотелось бы все-таки сделать как-то через хранение в бд.

Comment: У каждой записи элемента БД, должны быть два поля "Корень" - со ссылкой на верхний уровень, и "ЭтоПапка" - чтобы определить что этот элемент папка

Comment: @santavital еще нужно как-то хранить позицию расположения категории внутри ее уровня. Сами модели составить не проблема, нужно понять какой алгоритм лучше использовать и составлять уже для него. Например, я могу сделать структуру бд для Nested Sets, но не могу найти готовых модулей, чтобы затем взаимодействовать с этой структурой.

Comment: Я бы для категории сделал бы поля Id, Name, ParentId, SortOrder, и строил бы по этим данным дерево. При изменениях обновлял бы измененные узлы и все.

Comment: @tym32167 один `SortOrder`для хранения порядка не подойдет. Если в базе на одном уровне (с одинаковым `ParentId`) будет 1000 записей и мы вставляем запись в начало, придется обновлять `SortOrder` у всех этих записей.

Comment: @Skrim А будет ли на одном уровне 1000 записей? Это же категории, вы же их показывать на экране будете, я сомневаюсь, что у вас накопится 1000 подкатегорий. К тому же, можно сделать Order большим числом, например 1000, 2000, 3000 и тд, и вставку делать уже мегьшими числами, например между 1000 и 2000 вставить 1500. Обновлять соседние подкатегории только если места вставить между ними нет. На худой конец, если вас так сильно парит Order, делайте связный список тогда, типа NextId или PrevoiusId, но сортировать запаритесь с таким подходом

Comment: @tym32167 да, вы правы, с 1000 погорячился :) С `Next` и `Prev` уже запарился. Попробую все-таки через `SortOrder`

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вам необходимо определить классы **Категории** и **Продукта**, в самом простом случае они могут выглядеть так:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Тут другие нужный свойства...

    // Родительская категория.
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    // Дочерние категории.        
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }

    // Продукты в категории.
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Children = new List<Category>();
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Категории, в которых есть данный продукт.  
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

После того, как классы созданы - создаем конфигурацию, описывающую маппинг. Обратите внимание, что для простоты маппинг создан только для типа `Category` в нашем случае этого достаточно, т.к. `EF` интеллектуальный что бы сделать все остальное за нас. Если же вам необходимо настроить хранение типа `Product` отлично, от настроек по умолчанию, маппинг для него придется все-таки создать.

```
public class CategoryEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {            
        // Определяем связь между дочерними категориями.
        HasMany(p => p.Children).
            WithOptional(p => p.Parent);

        // Определяем связь между продуктами категориями.
        HasMany(p => p.Products)
            .WithMany(p => p.Categories);

        // Указание таблицы в БД.
        ToTable("Categories");
    }
}
```

После создания классов `Category`, `Product` и класса конфигурации `CategoryEntityTypeConfiguration`. Создаем контекст `EF`, который будет использоваться для взаимодействия с БД.

```
public class EfDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Сканируем всю сборку на поиск все конфигураций, описывающих маппинг.
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(EfDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Сама  программа:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Создаем список объектов, которые собираемся сохранить.
        var main = new Category()
        {
            Name = "Главная категория"
        };

        var firstSubCategory = new Category()
        {
            Name = "Дочерняя категория 1"
        };

        var secondSubCategory = new Category()
        {
            Name = "Дочерняя категория 2"
        };

        var product = new Product()
        {
            Name = "Продукт"
        };

        // Добавляем в главную категорию дочерние.
        main.Children.Add(firstSubCategory);
        main.Children.Add(secondSubCategory);

        // Добавляем в продукт в категории. 
        firstSubCategory.Products.Add(product);
        secondSubCategory.Products.Add(product);

        // Создаем контекст, добавляем в него данные и сохраняем. 
        var context = new EfDbContext();
        context.Set<Category>().Add(main);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, как этот ответ коррелирует с заданным вопросом?

Comment: Этот ответ как минимум показывает, как можно сохранить древовидную структуру в БД. Манипуляции вроде добавления, удаления, обновления сущностей здесь так же работают. Автор вроде этим и интересовался или я не прав?

Comment: Как я понял, автору надо 1) Хранить 2) перемещать (не только между уровнями, но и в рамках уровня) 3) Добавлять 4) Обновлять. Автор не уточнял, какой подход к хранению он предпочитает (code first vs db first), и как он собирается грузить данные (запихать все сразу в память или сделать ленивую загрузку). Ваш ответ показывает только один из способов настройки EF для сущностей, которые даже не до конца описаны (например, там нет поля order). Мало того, автор спрашивал о алгоритме, а не о его реализации. То есть, имхо, вы показали самую простую часть, которую, по сути, автор и не спрашивал.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что пункты 1, 2, 3 и 4 при данной настройке маппинга неосуществимы? Соглашусь, что перемещать внутри категории не получится, т.к. свойства `Order` нет. Но нет так же и свойства `Rating`, которое может пригодиться когда-нибудь, а может и нет. Если вы обратите внимание, в классе `Category` присутствует комментарий который говорит о том, что при желании сюда можно добавить нужные свойства. Ваше замечание относительно режима  работы `EF` и способе загрузки  данных, а  так же алгоритма я не уловил до конца. В целом, на что это влияет в ответе?

Comment: Пункты, конечно, осуществимы, но не показаны, а потому не являются частью ответа. Поле ```order``` касалось сортировки категорий с общим родителем (а эта сортировка присутствует в вопросе, см ```перемещать внутри и между уровнями```). Комментарий о возможности добавления полей - хорошо, Отсутствие полей для сортировки - не хорошо. Вы указали один конкретный способ применения EF - я не видел, чтобы автор упоминал, что ему нужен именно такой способ. По сути, автору нужен был алгоритм, а вы показали реализацию какой то его части, причем эту часть можно сделать разными способами.

Comment: Да что толку дискутировать, просто почитайте мой комментарий https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682921/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4/682936?noredirect=1#comment1003431_682921 , я посчитал, что автору нужен именно такой ответ, но как ответ егоне стал офорлять, так как  уж больно он короткий и не требует кода.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что дискутировать особо толку нет, и можно сходу кучу чего придумать и предложить. Проблема вся в том, что сценарии, как это все может использоваться обширны и не зная до конца контекста, можно прыгать из стороны в сторону. Поэтому и ответ был более абстрактным.

Comment: Да, я именно это и имею ввиду. Потому и начал эту дискуссию. Тем более что ваш ответ очень конкретный, но не отвечает на все поставленные абстрактные вопросы. В любом случае, пусть ценность ответа оценивают автор и сообщество. Вам спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: @sp7 спасибо за отклик, но, к сожалению, ваш ответ не раскрывает всех деталей. С созданием моделей и их конфигурацией проблем нет, хотелось понять какой алгоритм для хранения использовать и как взаимодействовать с данными в таком формате. Например, можно было бы воспользоваться моделью Nested Set, но у меня возникли сложности с созданием методов обновления данных под этот алгоритм. @tym32167 предложил использовать `SortOrder` с широким шагом, что я пока и реализовал.