# Как создать иерархию категорий?

Tags: c#

Идея в том, что есть категория у неё есть подкатегория и у этой подкатегории есть ещё категория. Использую EF Core. Сделал следующий объект

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly List<Category> _subcategories = new();

    private Category()
    {

    }

    public Category(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
    }

    public Category(string name, Category parentCategory) : this(name)
    {
        ParentCategory = parentCategory ??
                         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parentCategory));
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Category ParentCategory { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Category> Subcategories => _subcategories.AsReadOnly();

    protected internal void AddSubcategory(Category subcategory)
    {
        if (subcategory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subcategory));

        _subcategories.Add(subcategory);
    }

    protected internal void UpdateName(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
    }

    protected internal void UpdateParentCategory(Category parentCategory)
    {
        ParentCategory = parentCategory ?? 
                         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parentCategory));
    }
}
```

После создания миграции я получаю следующею таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда я получаю категорию с Id 8. В Subcategories я должен видеть категории под Id 9,10, но там только 9

Comment: Все верно. У Вас в БД так и записано у 8 есть 9, у 9 есть 10...категория с ID=10 не может быть подкатегорией 8

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak, я нашёл похожий вопрос, просто я не знаю как правильно заммапить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682921/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B4 

WithOptional в EF Core нет

Comment: Тип должен быть nullable, тогда он автоматически считается optional.

Comment: Не могу понять моя реализация правильная или нет?)

Comment: Правильная для чего? / В SQL есть несколько способов реализации [иерархических структур](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032). Вы используете список смежности. Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282863/184217

Comment: Как вы потом будете получать данные? В SQL для этого используются CTE. EF убог и не умеет их. Я бы порекомендовал [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html).

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете? Например, в Sql Server есть тип [hierarchyid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16). [Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16). В EF Core есть поддержка [SqlHierarchyId](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid?view=sql-dacfx-150).

Comment: Статья: [Using SQL Server HierarchyId with Entity Framework Core](https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm)